# Autocommand is executed multiple times on filetype

Tags: autocmd, filetype, formatting

I am trying to auto format python files on save.

### first.py

```python
#!/usr/bin/python3

print(     "first")
```

### second.py

```python
#!/usr/bin/python3

print(     "second")
```

### py.vim

```
def BlackFormat()
    :%!black --stdin-filename % -q -
    echom "black format done for file " .. expand("%")
enddef

autocmd FileType python autocmd BufWrite <buffer> call BlackFormat()
```

I start vim with `vim --clean -S py.vim first.py second.py`

Inside vim, I type,

```
:b2
:b1
:b2
:messages clear
:w
:messages
```

I see the below message,

```
3 lines filtered
black format done for file second.py
3 lines filtered
black format done for file second.py
"second.py" 3L, 36B written
```

The file is formatted twice. Every time I move to a buffer, a new call to format is added. I tried adding `++once` to second `autocmd`, didn't help. If I add to the first one, only the first file is formatted.

Is there a cleaner way to fix this? Not looking for plugins for python or auto-format. Trying to understand how to do it in vimscript.

---

### Update

Slightly modifying the solution in [this](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/43189) answer works good for me.

```
def BlackFormat()
    :%!black --stdin-filename % -q -
    echom "black format done for file " .. expand("%")
enddef

augroup BlackFormatAG
    autocmd FileType python autocmd! BlackFormatAG BufWrite <buffer> call BlackFormat()
augroup END

command DisableBlackFormat autocmd! BlackFormatAG
```

Comment: Do you still have something open in your question? How can we help you further? Otherwise maybe could you accept one of the answers using the v button next to the arrow voting buttons. It allow the question to rest :-)

Comment: accepted Thanks! Slightly modified as shown above in update.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that every time you switch to a `*.py` buffer its `filetype` is set and a new `autocommand BufWrite` is added to the stack.

Then when you write the buffer all the `autocommand BufWrite` are triggered.

To avoid that you could do:

```
vim9script

def BlackFormat()
    :%!black --stdin-filename % -q -
    echom "black format done for file " .. expand("%")
enddef

autocmd FileType python augroup BlackFormat | autocmd! BufWrite <buffer> call BlackFormat() | augroup END
```

With the `augroup BlackFormat` the `autocmd` belong to that `BlackFormat` group and with the `!` it override a previous occurrence of the `BufWrite` event in that `augroup` instead of adding another occurrence.

Comment: Hi it seems to work but the `augroup` part is not needed I think. Just adding `!` to `autocmd` seems to work. Also `augroup END` actually attaches to inner autocmd. When I run, `autocmd BufWrite`, I get `BlackFormat  BufWrite
    <buffer=1>
              call BlackFormat() | augroup END
`